How to determine the inquality direction of Pade Approximation of $\ln(x+1)$?
I'm confused about the general method to determine the inequality direction of Pade Approximation. From the bottom up, I consider the inequality direction of Taylor Expansion, for example,
$$
\ln(x+1)<x-\frac{x^2}{2},x\in(-1,0)
$$
and find we can use Lagrange remainder to determine that: for all $x\in(-1,0)$, we can find a $\xi\in(-1,0)$ that satisfies
$$
\ln(x+1)=\frac{\ln(0+1)}{0!}(x-0)^{0}+\frac{\frac{1}{0+1}}{1!}(x-0)^{1}+\frac{-\frac{1}{(0+1)^2}}{2!}(x-0)^2+\frac{2\frac{1}{(\xi+1)^3}}{3!}(x-0)^3
$$
and
$$
(\xi+1)^3x^3<0
$$
so
$$
\ln(x+1)<x-\frac{x^2}{2},x\in(-1,0)
$$
The trick could be applied on $\sin(x),\cos(x)$, etc.
However, when I try to consider the so-called Pade Approximation, I find
$$
(4x+6)\ln(x+1)<(4x+6)(x-\frac{x^2}{2})=6x+x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^3>6x+x^2,x\in(-1,0)
$$
So I can't determine the relation between $\ln(x+1)$ and $\frac{6x+x^2}{4x+6}$. Of course, we can just use brute force to do derivative. But I wonder whether we can determine it by some regular patterns, instead of just calling the function an 'Approximation'?

This may help: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+log%281%2Bx%29-%28x-x%5E2%2F2%29%2C+log%281%2Bx%29-+%28x%5E2%2B6x%29%2F%284x%2B6%29%2C+-0.5%3Cx%3C0.5  Both are essentially Pade Approximations around $x=0$, but of different order polynomials for denominators.

Let $P_n$ be the $[n,n]$ Padé approximant of $\log(x+1)$ built around $x=0$.
We have the nice
$$\log(x+1)-P_n=\frac{(n!)^4 }{(2 n)! \,\,(2 n+1)!}\,\,x^{2 n+1}~\sim ~2\pi \,\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^{2 n+1}$$
Notice that, with respect to the infinite norm,
$$P_2=\frac{3 x (x+2)}{x^2+6 x+6}$$ is better than $\frac{6x+x^2}{4x+6}$.
The integrals have closed forms but I shall just report the numerical values
$$\int_{-1}^0 \left(\log (x+1)-\frac{6x+x^2}{4 x+6}\right)^2\,dx=0.203452$$
$$\int_{-1}^0 \left(\log (x+1)-\frac{3 x (x+2)}{x^2+6 x+6}\right)^2\,dx=0.124875$$
I suppose that you have been using [this paper].

That formula for $\log(x+1)-P_n$ cannot be true since $\log$ is not a rational function.
